# How To create a Custom .hasError condition in angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom-events

I'm working on changing an html form that used to have required fields to now become optional fields. The checks in place on those fields used to have .hasError('required') implemented, and this caused the submit button to be disabled by sending off an error that listeners would pick up. I still need the submit button to be disabled when they fill out the optional fields incorrectly, but can't use 'required' anymore, and in this case using 'minlength' or 'maxlength'checks also don't apply. Is there a way to make a custom .hasError ? Or is there a way to manually emit an error when this type of error occurs?

Below is the old line which successfully made the button disable, and the line I'm currently using which has the correct checks and displays what is desired, but will not disable the button.

```
<span class="haserror"*ngIf="editMode&&canPersistUser&&accountForm.get('passwordInfo').get('rpassword').touched && 
accountForm.get('passwordInfo').get('rpassword').hasError('required') && editMode">This Field can not be left empty.</span>
```

and

```
<span class="has-error"*ngIf="editMode && canPersistUser && accountForm.get('passwordInfo').get('password').value != ''  
&&accountForm.get('passwordInfo').get('rpassword').pristine  && editMode">You must confirm your password if you plan to set one up.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show code how you create `FormGroup`?

Whenever you remove `Validators.required` and leave other validators the form group should have member `invalid` set to true so you can use on sumbit button something like:

```
   <button [disabled]="accountForm.invalid"></button>
```